# Javascript, File Input and FormData issue

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, javascript-objects

I am having an issue passing a file input object through to a function that prepares and adds to an Object Array before feeding it into a form data array.

To simplify this, i have broken it down to the following.

```
case "file":
    values[input_name] = inputs[i].files[0];
break;  
return values;
```

If I read the file into an Object Array

```
values{"imagename": file}
```

Before  passing that object into a formData object

```
formParams.append("imagename", file);
```

Which i am doing through an entire object with the following loop

```
var formParams = new FormData();
for (key in values) {
    formParams.append(key, values[key]);
    log("error", "FormData Key: " + key + " Data:" + values[key]);
}
```

the `FormData` Object doesn't seem to pass the actual file, yet it passes the `FileList` data, the name, size, etc.

My question is, can the file itself be passed to an object and kept in tact, it seems i am losing the filedata of the image being uploaded.

When the form is processed by `PHP` at the other end, it doesn't populate the `$_FILES` array, and the PHP process function fails as it doesn't see any data for the respective Input Field.

Am I losing the file data by passing the file to an object before passing it to FormData?

Comment: Are you setting `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`?

Comment: Yes, i am passing a newly created form object `var form = document.createElement('form');` to the formData and setting `form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';` to that form.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to the `FormData` object the form element you're trying to send:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

  var formParams = new FormData(form);
  // here you can perform your ajax request

  ev.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

I am not sure you need the block

```
for (key in values) {
  formParams.append(key, values[key]);
  log("error", "FormData Key: " + key + " Data:" + values[key]);
}
```

Unless you're adding more key/pairs value you should be able to remove it safely.

Comment: The form is already submitted, the forms inputs, selects, textareas, etc are collated into an array, the array is manipulated, a handful of extra key values are added, and that is the values{} object that is returned to be processed by the append loop.

Comment: The file seems to be non existant by the mere passing of image.files[0] to values{"image": file} before it gets to FormData.append("image":file)

Comment: I should add, this form works perfectly without the file data.

Comment: What does your form looks like?

Comment: I found this article in MDN about form data, where there is also a file upload in the example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: standard and simple form with 34 fields, images are input/file which are added by javascript after the form is loaded.  This is then processed through a javascript function which pulls all the forms entries into an object array which is sorted, some fields are edited, and extra key/values are added to the array before it is sent to formData to be sent via AJAX.  The form itself is a retail management form, so takes textareas, selects, input/text, all these fields process fine.  It is the `var imagefile = image.files[0]` where it seems that this copy loses file data, but leaves the file list.

Comment: i know how to use a FormData Object, i am using one to process through AJAX already.  My concern here is losing the image along the way.

Comment: How do you process the ajax call for the image upload?